# What is the best way to embed Youtube videos?

Tags: php, html, iframe, youtube, embed

I'm building a video website and I want my users to be able to upload or embed videos from Youtube. The Youtube API doesn't seem to provide video upload from their website, or do they?
So I tried to embed videos via an `iframe` with PHP. Here is the code:

```
<?php
$source=$_POST['source'];
?>

<html>
<div id="bo"><?php echo $source;?></div>
<form action="altupload.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="source">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</html>
```

But all I get is:

```
<html><div id="bo"><iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/tZa5hyb0_wA\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>`

<html>
<form action="altupload.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="source">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</html>
```

Can anyone recommend some other ways to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allow the user upload only youtube video ID from URL as :

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vw5FDZRGTL0
```

video ID  : `Vw5FDZRGTL0`

and you can set other options of IFrame tag :

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $videoID; ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `addslashes()` function:

```
echo Addslashes($source);
```